# What should I do if behavior of subclass doesn't corresponds behavior of superclass?

Tags: class, oop, inheritance, subclass, superclass

So I recently learn about OOP principles. And one question is very interesting for me. So, for instance, I have MobilePhones class and its subclasses such as Nokia, Samsung, Iphone and etc. If I define **takePhoto()** method in superclass, what should I do to subclasses that doesn't support **takePhoto** behavior? Is there other way except overriding?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another class called `SmartPhone` which extends `MobilePhone`.

Then you move the definition of `takePicture()` from `MobilePhone` to `SmartPhone`.

All phones which support the `takePhoto` behavior  should extends `SmartPhone`, while others have to extends `MobilePhone`.

I hope that this idea help you :D

Comment: Greaaat! Thanks very much, exactly what I was looking for!